Why can I hear a radio station when probing with oscilloscope?
I assembled this on a breadboard:

and am hearing a faint buzzing sound...
My first question is, what could be causing this sound?  It does not go away if I connect VIN to ground.  With or without VIN connected to ground, probing the input to the speaker looks a little suspect (please see scope screenshot below).
My second question is, why can I hear a radio station when I connect my oscilloscope probe to VIN?  I was very surprised, and I have to put my ear close to the speaker to hear it, the sound of the buzz is louder than the radio station.  If I remove the probe from VIN the music goes away and it's just the buzz.  Put it back in and I #$%^ you not, I am bent over with my ear right next to the speaker listening to Shania Twain right now.
Here is a photo -- the resistors and capacitor to the left are for other prototyping related to shrinking a DAC 0-3.3V output and removing the DC offset... to feed into the LM386:



This IC has poor power supply rejection, meaning a good fraction of any noise on the positive supply (with respect to ground) will appear at the output. The manufacturer's solution for this seems to be to connect a bypass capacitor of 10μF between pin 7 and ground. That should kill a lot of the noise without affecting bandwidth. This isn't well documented in the datasheet.
As for radio pickup, how you solve that depends on where the accidental antenna is. All the wires on your breadboard are long, very good antennae, so the RF source could be anywhere. The best solution will be to get all of those wires to be as short as possible.
If the RF source is the power supply rail, then installing the bypass capacitor above will already have improved things, but power supply decoupling will still be necessary. Connect a 100nF ceramic capacitor across the LM386 power supply pins, 6 and 4, as close to those pins as possible.
Since you have a DAC providing the input signal, and you are trying to reduce overall gain from 20 down to somewhere near 1, then you might try a capacitor at the input to suppress RF, C2 here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If RF is finding its way into the system elsewhere, then the brute force solution is to limit bandwidth, which you can do by placing a 100pF capacitor between pins 5 and 1. This produces strong negative feedback (which reduces gain) at frequencies over 20kHz, but I am not sure how that will affect the stability of the amplifier. Give it a shot if all else fails.

You are dealing with an amplifier IC that is very capable of amplifying both wanted and unwanted signals, and you have built the circuit around it in a way that does not really try to prevent it much from amplifying unwanted signals, more like in a way that allows unwanted disturbance signals to get amplified.
With a circuit built and used like that, it is even not very surprising there are issues, such as hearing a nearby radio station, you explicitly need to build the circuit in a way that takes these problems into account and prevents noise and radio signals from getting amplified.
For example, the chip has no power supply bypass (filter) caps at all, and you seem to be powering it from the Nucleo board, which very likely gets powered with a noisy switch mode power supply of the computer or phone charger. The buzzing might also be due to the MCU consuming power periodically, depending on what it does. For example, even some USB audio interfaces that you can record your guitar etc can have some measurable buzzing at 1 kHz, because the audio is sent over USB as a burst transmission packet every 1ms.
Also all that wiring leaping around in loops are just antennas capable of both transmitting and receiving electromagnetic interference. Including transmissions of nearby radio stations. The parasitic capacitances and inductances of the jumper wires and inside the breadboard may even help to be sensitive to some specific station.
The RF signal is not heard directly but all it takes is some nonlinear element like a PN junction of a diode or transistor inside the LM386 which demodulates the audio from the RF transmission for amplification.
So, at least what you can do is add bypass caps for power supply and other caps as suggested by the LM386 data sheet. This is to prevent supply from sagging under demand when chip needs current. The capacitors must have as short wiring as possible to LM386 supply pins (so it must be near it but also wires and wire loop minimized).
The audio inputs also need some small filter caps to shunt RF signals, right at the chip input. Value should be selected so that it does not affect your audio, which depends on your audio output. Maybe few hundred pF to a few nF.
